# Intellij IDEA hanging in scala projects

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am using `Intellij IDEA` and `SBT` for my scala project. I have a laptop with **intel i7** and **16GB RAM**. The intellij IDEA completely hangs while using. The CPU usage is most of the times above 50% and even goes to 100% many times. 
I have used IntelliJ in java projects for no issues at all.

Can someone helps me to solve this problem. Not just me, my friends are also facing the same issues in intellij.

IntelliJ Version: tried with 13.1 and 14

`UPDATE`: I updated the IntelliJ version to `14.0.2` and it is now working well without any delay.

Comment: did you use the latest hotfix for IntelliJ 14?

Comment: I downloaded the latest one last week only. What is the hotfix? I am facing the issue in both 13 and 14.

Comment: I have not had problems using SBT with IntelliJ both 13 and 14. Can you provide example use case and or code?

Comment: It is not for any specific case. Especially if 2 intellij are open, it is surely going to hang. If i try to edit one line, there is a delay of 2-3 seconds.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the document [Reporting performance problems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/29983118-Reporting-performance-problems) and submit a report to JetBrains. Also, as @ozOli suggests, make sure you are using IDEA v14.0.1 and v1.1.1 of the scala plug-in. Both were released on 14 November 2014.

Comment: Also... make sure your JVM memory settings in the IDEA .vmoptions or .plist (Mac) file are set to `-Xms2048m` and `-Xmx2048m`. The scala plug-in should prompt you at start-up if they are not. This was a recent change.